# How to construct an axis label with both normal, italic and bold font

Tags: r, graph, plot

I would like to construct the following x axis label

bla bla *bli bli* bla **blom** bla

(normal normal italic italic normal bold italic)

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: Is it also possible to change the font?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
   plot(1,1, xlab= expression(bla~bla~italic(bli~bli)~bla~bold(blom)~italic(bla)))
```

Read the `?plotmath` page for further options.

Comment: Perfect. Now, sorry to change the question a bit but is it possible to  also change the font?

Comment: `text` and `mtext` have font arguments. The choices will be determined by the graphics device, so you will need to be more specific, preferably with an example and details about OS and target output type.

Comment: @DWin, I would propose the same, but using bquote. What are the differences between expression and bquote?

Comment: Good point. `bquote` gives you the added capacity to insert interpreted values inline with the expression. It wasn't needed here but if one of those "bla"'s or "bli"'s had been an object or part of an object, then its value could have been been "dropped in". If you wnat values put in using `expression` you need to use `substitute`.

Comment: There's also a subtle distinction btwn the value returned, since 'bquote' actually returns an unevaluated 'call'-object. At one point that seemed to make a difference in lattice plotting functions, but I haven't seen it as a problem recently.