# In R, how to get powers of ten in bold font in a plot label?

Tags: r, plot

I want to have "10^4 points" in bold as my x-axis label.

I know how to make a simple label in bold:

```
plot(1:10, xlab="")
mtext(text="10 points", side=1, font=2, line=3)
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216832/597069), I know how to make a label with a power of ten but nothing is in bold:

```
mtext(text=expression(paste(10^4, " points")), side=1, font=2, line=3)
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047422/597069), I also know how to make a label with a Greek letter in bold:

```
mtext(text=expression(bold(paste(beta, "=", 10^1, " points"))), side=1, line=3)
```

But still the power of ten is not in bold!

It doesn't work either with `bquote`:

```
mtext(text=bquote(bold(10^1~points)), side=1, line=3)
```

Any idea?

Here are some details about my system. Let me know if you need anything else.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use "4" instead of a numeric 4.

```
mtext(text=expression(paste(10^bold("4"), " points")), side=1, font=2, line=3)
```

By the way this is yet-another-case where the plotmath `paste` is not needed:

```
mtext(text=expression(10^bold("4")~points), side=1, font=2, line=3)
```

I see you cited one of my earlier postings on plotmath and find that the link to Prof Ripley's 2010 posting was to the old finzi server which no longer carries the load for rhelp searches. I've [updated that link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-March/232923.html).

Comment: only "4" is in bold. So I tried this: mtext(text=expression(bold(10^bold("4")~points)), side=1, font=2, line=3). Now everything is in bold except the "10" itself. Thus I had to do this to finally get what I wanted: mtext(text=expression(bold(bold("10")^bold("4")~points)), side=1, font=2, line=3).

Comment: I thought getting the 4 as bold was what you wanted. Looking at your question now, you were saying "But still the power of ten is not in bold!". The relevant section of the plotmath help page is this: "Note that bold, italic and bolditalic do not apply to symbols, and hence not to the Greek symbols such as mu which are displayed in the symbol font. They also do not apply to numeric constants."

Comment: Maybe your next question should be to request a programmatic way to scroll across an expression and surround the numeric values by `bold(.)`. I'm sure it's possible but may take one of the higher beings. Working with language objects often requires using a different set of functions.